# Examples of a function that have many zeros near $0$ with nonzero derivative at $0$

Tags: real-analysis

Is there a function $f:[a,b]\to\Bbb R$ that satisfies:

- $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$
- $f(0)=0$
- $f'(0)\neq 0$
- $f$ have
  infinitely zeros near $0$, i.e., $0$ is a cluster/limit point of the set
  $\{x\mid f(x)=0\}$

I think it might be related to the function $\sin(1/x)$ or $x^k\sin(1/x)$, but I can't construct one. Need help. The difficult parts are probably how to make $f'(0)\neq 0$. I'd tried $f(x)=x+x^2\sin(1/x)$, but this function unfortunately doesn't have infinitely many zeros near $0$, the term $x$ lifts too high the function near $0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't need the function to be differentiable at $0$, then $f(x) = x\sin(1/x)$ will do fine (with the obvious addition $f(0) = 0$).

If you need your function to be differentiable at $0$, then the infinitely many zeroes close to $x = 0$ force $f'(0) = 0$, because the fraction
$$
\frac{f(x) - f(0)}{x - 0}
$$
is zero infinitely many times close to $x = 0$, and by definition of derivative, the limit of the above fraction as $x\to 0$ exists and must be $0$, which makes $f'(0) = 0$.

Comment: Thanks. I can understand if the limit exists, this should be $0$. However, I can't quickly see why the limit must exists?

Comment: I think maybe you mean $f(x)=x^2\sin(1/x)$, because otherwise the ratio is $\sin(1/x)$ which fluctuates arbitrarily, despite being 0 infinitely many times.

Comment: @Eric Because that's the definition of differentiable.

Comment: @AlexR. But that function is 1) differentiable at $x = 0$ and 2) has derivative $0$ at $x = 0$ (provided you append the function value $0$ at $x = 0$). I specifically wanted to avoid those two things.

Comment: Pardon, I assumed that you're still using $f(x)$ in your second sentence,

Answer (score 0):

Take the function
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}
0 & \text{ if } x=0\\
x^P\sin(x^{-q}) & \text{ if } x \ne 0,
\end{cases}
$$
where $p-1>q> 0$.